# How to know cursor position index in an editor

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, visual-studio

I'm working with an HTML file, and I need to know my cursor position **index** in the overall file.

In Visual Studio, I can see the **line number** and **column number** in status bar.

In Notepad++ too, in the status bar, **line number** and **column number** are shown.

But I need to know the **index** of the cursor. For example, instead of **line 4 column 23**, I want to know that I'm at the **256th** character in the file.

Does any editor exist out there with this feature?

Comment: in the end, notepad++ has this feature, but VS is not ... wow, I'm truly amazed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### I need to know the index of the cursor.

> For example, instead of line 4 column 23, I want to know that I'm at the 256th character in the file.**

Notepad++ already has the feature you are looking for.

1. Select all characters from the current cursor position to the start of the file using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>
2. Look at the status bar where it says "Sel: *characters*|*rows*"

   - **The first value *characters* is the number of characters in the selection**.
   - The second value *rows* is the number of rows in the selection.
   - The selection starts from the beginning of the file and ends where the cursor was previously .
   - **The value of *characters* is the "index" of the cursor.**

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Note that *characters* includes the end of line characters.

Comment: Note that char position is different than actual *byte* offset in the file for UTF-8 encoding or Unicode files in general. Use Ctrl+G and in **Go To...** dialog switch to **Offset** for *You are here* value to show *byte* offset no matter file encoding.

Answer (score 13):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and click the `Offset` radio button. Your cursor position will be shown in the `You are here:` line

Example:

[image: Notepad++ "Go To..." window]